# Setting up Rsnapshot for casual manual backup?

Tags: linux, backup, rsnapshot

I am confused with new Rsnapshot configuration. In current version there is a different way of specifiying backup intervals, like so:

```
retain hourly  2
retain weekly  7
retain monthly 2
```

I would like to do a manual backup few times a month. I'd like to have 3 archives saved. How should I set up the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: replace this with

```
retain manual 3
```

and run `rsnapshot manual` whenever you'd like to do a backup.

The default configuration defines three different “backup levels.”  The idea is that you run `rsnapshot hourly` every few hours, `rsnapshot weekly` every week, and `rsnapshot monthly` every month (usually from cron jobs).  When `rsnapshot weekly` gets run, it moves the oldest `hourly` backup to a `weekly` backup; when `rsnapshot monthly` gets run, it moves the oldest `weekly` backup to a `monthly` backup.

The names for these backup levels, however, are totally arbitrary – there's nothing about rsnapshot that requires you to back up hourly, weekly, and daily.  So if you just replace the backup levels with one of your own – a `manual` level – you can just run `rsnapshot manual` whenever you want, and it'll do a full incremental backup of whatever you've selected in rsnapshot.conf.